# pyhton3 program with function name thue morse sequence

Tags: python-3.x

Building Thue-Morse sequence. In this task you are required to write a Python function named thue_morse(n), that takes a positive integer parameter, n, and returns the string tn (defined above). In your program you may define other (auxiliary) functions with arbitrary names, however, the solution function of this task should be named thue_morse(n).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def thue_morse(n):
    tn = "0"
    for i in range(n):
        prev = tn
        for bin_dig in tn:
            if bin_dig == "0":
                prev += "1"
            else:
                prev += "0"
        tn = prev
    return tn
```

Comment: There's definitely a better way to solve it. This is what's called a brute force approach, but it does work. See wikipedia for more insight.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence